# Autowire Service bean into an XML defined bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my Spring Application, I have a bean defined in my xml as such:

```
<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="com.myproject.core.security.RemoteTokenStore" />
```

I also have this class I created, and annotated with @Service:

```
com.myproject.core.service.CacheService
```

In my RemoteTokenStore.java file, if I try to Autowire CacheService like so:

```
@Autowired
private CacheService cacheService;
```

It is always null. How to I fix this?

Comment: In some cases it will be usefull to know how to mix xml defined beans with references to autowired ones. Do anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your context xml file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.core.security" />
```

Once this has been specified your annotations will be processed and your components will be identified by Spring.

If you haven't already you will also need to include the `spring-context` dependency on your classpath and the context namespace in your application XML.

Reading this: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/ might help

Comment: This is not completely true. `<context:annotation-config/>` is enough to enable many annotations (like `Autowired`) but you need the above Scan to make Spring search for Annotated components that are not described in the XML.

Comment: Updated answer so it is not misleading :)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't give enough information. which spring version? which application server?

in general, you should have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.packagebase" />
```

in your spring xml conf files to use annotated beans.

however, it won't always work.

I had problem with spring 2.5.6 + Jboss AS7. Jboss kept reporting annotated bean not defined. (NoSuchBeanDefinition or something like that). I switched to spring 3.0.0.Relase to resolve it.